# Find the cartesian equation of: $y = \sin (2t)$ and $x = \cos (t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

$\eqalign{
  & y = \sin (2t)  \cr 
  & x = \cos (t) \cr} $

therefore:

$\eqalign{
  & \sin (t) = {y \over {2\cos t}}  \cr 
 as: & \cos (t) = x  \cr 
  & {\rm{ sin(t) = }}{y \over {2x}}  \cr 
 using: & {\sin ^2}t + {\cos ^2}t = 1  \cr 
  & {\rm{ }}{x^2} + {\left( {{y \over {2x}}} \right)^2} = 1  \cr 
  & {x^2} + {{{y^2}} \over {4{x^2}}} = 1 \cr} $

---

My question is, is there anything wrong with leaving it in this form? is there a "cartesian" form I must adhere to? The answer in the textbook decides to tackle it in a different manner and achieves a different result (which I am able to achieve through my method too), the answer in the textbook is:

$\eqalign{
  & y = 2\sin (t)\cos (t)  \cr 
  & {\sin ^2}t + {x^2} = 1  \cr 
  & {\sin ^2}t = 1 - {x^2}  \cr 
  & \sin t = \sqrt {1 - {x^2}}   \cr 
  & y = (2\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} )x  \cr 
  & y = 2x\sqrt {1 - {x^2}}  \cr} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is more correct in some sense. For instance, take $t=-\pi/3$. We get $$x=\cos(t) = 1/2 \text{ and } y=\sin(2t) = \sin(-2 \pi/3) = - \sqrt{3}/2,$$ which is admissible according to your equation
$$x^2 + \dfrac{y^2}{4x^2} = 1$$
whereas the book solution for $x=1/2$ gives $y = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2$, which is not correct.

Comment: How is that incorrect?  For $t = \frac{\pi}{3} , x = 1/2$ and $y = \sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  What _is_ inadequate about the book's answer is that this is a Lissajous figure.  Assad's answer is reasonable because the curve does have four-fold symmetry about the origin.  The solver's for the book ignored the fact that the "negative square-root" is also admissible.  The curve looks like a "figure-eight", whearas the solver's curve is only an "S-shaped" half of the full figure.

Comment: $y=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ excludes the possibility $(1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was looking at the original parametric description.  Both square-roots should be included...  (The solver for the text upholds the 0.5 to 2% error-rate in text-book solutions.)  There _is_ an oddity in the Cartesian description at $x = 0$, due to the fact that the curve crosses itself there; this is why parametric forms are sometimes to be preferred...